# On Click of button on LWC I want to open a new tab and write html code that has come as a response from rest call

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying some thing like

```
getSelectedReport({ Url: url })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);

        // var newWindow = window.open();
        // newWindow.document.write(result);
        //newWindow.close();
        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=1000,height=1000");
        myWindow.document.write(result);
        
     }).catch((error) => {
          this.isModalOpen = true;
        this.error = error;
        console.log("error Occured " + error);
      });
  }
```

in the above code I want to open a new tab and have the html code in it that was passed on by Apex controller .

But I am getting error saying cannot find attribute write on null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locker Service doesn't allow you to write directly to `document`. You can demonstrate this in the [Locker Console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console). With the example code

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=1000,height=1000");
myWindow.document.write("foo");
```

You'll find with Locker turned on, you get an error

> Error: myWindow.document is undefined

while the expected result occurs when you turn Locker off. You can also see the [Locker Service Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) documents that `document.write()` is not available.

---

You'll need to rethink how you're building your component. Reflecting HTML from some Apex code into the DOM is not generally a great idea anyway (it's very easy to do things wrong that result in XSS or other unpleasant attacks and misbehaviors).

If you must mutate your *own* DOM (as opposed to some other window's), you may wish to use the `lwc:dom="manual"` property. See the [LWC Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_third_party_library) for more. But you must, again, but extremely cognizant of security and the context of the data you are seeking to inject.

Comment: In addition, Lightning Web Security distorts [window.open](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/lws-distortion-viewer) to restrict access to just `close`, `focus`, `postMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option here is to not open a new window, but simply put the HTML into an element in your component.

---

```
<div></div>
```

---

```
async myFunction() {
  let url = '...';
  let result = await getSelectedReport({ url });
  this.template.querySelector('div').innerHTML = result;
}
```

This should work in both Locker Service and Lightning Web Security. In addition, your inputs will automatically be sanitized to prevent XSS and unwanted scripts from running.